# Using Variable Text Features in Machine Learning Model

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I am building a classification model using deidentified patient data with ICD-10 codes as inputs. Each code is a string and represents a diagnosis, and these follow the pattern of 1 letter, followed by 2 digits, followed by numbers and/or letters. However, patients can have multiple associated ICD-10 codes, so I am not sure how to handle this. There are some logical groupings, though, and the initial letter of the code represents a general category of diagnoses (e.g. cardiovascular).

A patient may have multiple ICD-10 codes. For instance, if a patient has hypertension and diabetes, this may be I1310 and E119.

My naive approach would be to make, say, 10 columns for each patient [diagnosis 1, diagnosis 2, etc.] and use that as training data. However, this has the issue that, for instance, even if two patients both have diabetes, patient A may have this as diagnosis 2 but patient B may have this as diagnosis 4. I am assuming this would hinder the model from training properly.

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?